# Does virtual memory cause certain actions to become permanently unusable?

Tags: memory

If you send a transaction which takes exactly max-transaction-time in RAM, does this mean this transaction can never be executed when database data is requested which has been moved to disk (virtual memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOSIO database is only in RAM, it never moves to virtual memory. This is a trade-off prioritizing performance over size.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, so what data will be moved to virtual memory and when, and what performance difference will the end-user experience in such cases?

Comment: No data will move to virtual memory